# Autoslider check

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slide

I created this little autoslider:

http://jsfiddle.net/5H5Xq/43/

Part of this auto-slider is my auto.slide.function:

```
var i = 0, max = 3;
myFunction = function(event){
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
    i += 1;
    if(i >= max) { i = 0; }
}
```

So every five seconds the image changes.

How to check which image is currently shown?

Like this:

```
var src =$('#newImage img').attr('src')

if ( src == "path/to/img1" ) { .. 
if ( src == "path/to/img2" ) { ..
if ( src == "path/to/img3" ) { ..
```

But this doesn't work, cause the image switches using `display:none/block`.

Anybody could tell me how to check which image is currently shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element is visible by doing

```
$('img').is(':visible');
```

To check a group of elements you could use each.

```
$('.images img').each(function()
{
    if($(this).is(':visible'))
    {
        console.log($(this)); //this is visible
    }
});
```

If your slider is mid transition there will be multiple visible.

Comment: yea ok but how to specify this on one of three image´s ? that´s my main problem.. thanks!

Comment: ok but using this, every image is "visible" : Object[img thumb73.jpg]

Object[img thumb72.jpg]
Object[img thumb61h.jpg]

Comment: this is output of console. i just need one image every five second´s, you know a workaround?